# Code not executing when awaiting dispatch in for loop

Tags: react-native, redux

I can not find anything on this so I decided to ask it here.
I am using react-native and redux.
I left the business logic out of the code.

I have this function which calls another function that does an API call.
The function that does the API call needs to access "getState", that's the reason I use dispatch.

```
const getStuff = (day) => (dispatch) => {
    const result = await dispatch(functionThatDoesAPIRequest(day)
    }
```

Then I have this code that loops over days and in some cases needs to do the API call. In the case I was testing it does not need to access the API. I could not find the problem with my code until I placed the line between the if statement in comments. Then I changed the if to always be False and the error persisted when the line of code was not in comments, even though it could never reach that piece of code.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < dayArray.length; i+=1) {
      if (false) {
       const resultThatIsNotNeeded = await dispatch(getStuff(dayArray[i])
      }
      // more business logic
    }
```

Changing the for loop to a ForEach loop fixed this issue somehow. But I really have no clue why this fixed it.

```
dayArray.forEach(async (day, i) => {
  if (false) {
    const resultThatIsNotNeeded = await dispatch(getStuff(dayArray[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because on your forEach the await call is inside of a async function as it should be
On the for loop I don't see any of this code being executed within a async function

Comment: The function that calls the for loop is also Async. I read online that the for loop should support await. Or is that not correct?